# Simple pagination Multiple pages, using multiple css selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I'm using [simple pagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) to run my website, but I've ran into a problem. I have css tabs that is my navigation, in each navigation i have a separate pagination that differs from the previous one.

jquery pagination code

```
$(function(){
var perPage = 8;
var opened = 1;
var onClass = 'on';
var paginationSelector = '.pages';
$('.gallery').simplePagination(perPage, opened, onClass, paginationSelector);
});
```

.gallery is used to call the style of the gallery i'm assuming, but the only way to use this code (AS FAR AS I KNOW) is to call it a second time.

```
$(function(){
var perPage = 8;
var opened = 1;
var onClass = 'on';
var paginationSelector = '.pages2';
$('.gallery2').simplePagination(perPage, opened, onClass, paginationSelector);
});
```

> my first question, is there a way to simplify the code, where i dont
>   have to repeat each jquery call?

Second question, regardless of that, when i try to call the same css code

```
.gallery, .gallery2 {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    margin: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    height: 552px;
    width:850px;
}

 .gallery, .gallery2 li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    background: #E6E6FA;
    border: 1px solid #999999; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    height: 255px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px; 
    }
```

This code does not work, i have to separate the code for each gallery on its own, then it works. I mean i could manage, but 1 edit means i have to edit 5+ times. Any idea why this is not working?

I'm assuming it doesnt work because of this call. It's looking for .gallery? correct? is there a way to alter the code to make multiple class selections possible?

```
$('.gallery').simplePagination(perPage, opened, onClass, paginationSelector);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will bind the pagination event to elements with either classes (gallery2 and gallery)

```
$(function(){
    var perPage = 8;
    var opened = 1;
    var onClass = 'on';
    $('.gallery').simplePagination(perPage, opened, onClass, '.pages');
    $('.gallery2').simplePagination(perPage, opened, onClass, '.pages2');
});
```

You could at least do it this way, not sure how many pages you have or how your code looks like. Could be solved by a loop adding 1 (or nothing if i == 1),2,3 etc after "gallery" and "pages".

Last css change to
`.gallery li, .gallery2 li`

Comment: @Sickest Did you try this?

Comment: The css code worked perfectly, stupid mistake of me not adding the li with each selector, but im noob so yea. BUT the jquery code does not work, when i seperate the function it works fine, but not the way your code is unfortunately

Comment: i updated my question, it needs to be .pages2 not .pages, it won't allow me to call pages more then once.